# What is global loading extras in SystemJS and how to use it?

Tags: systemjs, single-spa

Currently, I have a project using single-spa for implementing micro-frontend. I have read The Recommended Setup from the single-spa page and found that I can use global loading for the shared library. I have read this global loading in SystemJS README but I still don't know how to use it.

Docs:

Single-spa: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup#systemjs

SystemJS: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#extras

Could you please give me an example or instruction to use the global loading feature of SystemJS? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Global loading extra is already included](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#2-systemjs-loader) if you are using the system.js build (versus the s.js minimal loader) so you do not need to include anything else. root-config projects generated by
create-single-spa [use the system.js build](https://github.com/single-spa/create-single-spa/blob/main/packages/generator-single-spa/src/root-config/templates/src/index.ejs#L62).

Comment: I have one more question: Does global loading support load non System.register format in root-config? (It means that I can use any vanilla JS version of package hosted on cdnjs, jsDelivr or unpkg? Thank a lot